# In jqgrid Millisecond in time column not showing properly

Tags: jqgrid-formatter

I want to show hour,minute,second and milliseconds in time column of my jqgrid but millisecond is not showing and while modifing millisecond field showing wrong data.

This is my used code:

```
{ 
    text: 'Time', filterable: false, datafield: 'Time', width: '120px', 
    cellsFormat: "HH:mm:ss.fff", 
    createfilterwidget: function (column, columnElement, logReportSearchGrid){ 
        $(logReportSearchGrid).jqxDateTimeInput({ 
            formatString: 'MM/dd/yyyy', 
            dropDownHorizontalAlignment: 'right' 
        }); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: When adding code to your post you should format it properly so it is readable.